# C# Reference: Line updates its EndPoint due to changed from different Line instance

Tags: c#

Right in to the point, I have classes Point, Line

```
    public class Point
    {
        public double X{get;set;}
        public double Y{get;set;}
        public Point(double x, double y) { this.X = x, this.Y = y}
    }
    public class Line
    {
        public Point StartPoint { get; set; }
        public Point EndPoint { get; set; }
        public Line(Point StartPoint, Point EndPoint)
        {
            this.StartPoint = StartPoint;
            this.EndPoint = EndPoint;
        }
        public double GetLength()
        {
            double x0 = StartPoint.X;
            double y0 = StartPoint.Y;
            double x1 = EndPoint.X;
            double y1 = EndPoint.Y;
            double vtx = x1 - x0;
            double vty = y1 - y0;
            return Math.Sqrt(vtx * vtx + vty * vty);
        }
        public double GetAngle()
        {
            double x0 = StartPoint.X;
            double y0 = StartPoint.Y;
            double x1 = EndPoint.X;
            double y1 = EndPoint.Y;
            double vtx = x1 - x0;
            double vty = y1 - y0;
            return Math.Atan2(vty, vtx) / Math.PI * 180;
        }
        public void SetLength(double l)
        {
            double ag = this.GetAngle();
            double x2 = StartPoint.X+ l * Math.Cos(ag);
            double y2 = StartPoint.Y+ l * Math.Sin(ag);
            EndPoint = new Point(x2, y2);
        }
        public void SetAngle(double ag)
        {
            double l = this.GetLength();
            double x2 = StartPoint.X+ l * Math.Cos(ag);
            double y2 = StartPoint.Y+ l * Math.Sin(ag);
            EndPoint = new Point(x2, y2);
        }
    }
```

Take example:

```
 var p0 = new Point(0,0) ;
 var p1 = new Point(1,0) ;
 var p2 = new Point(2,0) ;
 var p3 = new Point(3,0) ;

 var line0 = new Line(p0,p1);
 var line1 = new Line(p1,p2); 
 var line2 = new Line(p2,p3);

 Line1.SetLength(2); //Line1 StartPoint will be (0,0) Endpoint (2,0)
```

I want the result to be:

```
 //line0's change effects all others lines
 //line2 auto updates to StartPoint (2,0) Endpoint (3,0)
 //line3 auto updates to StartPoint (3,0) Endpoint (4,0)
```

Now the user sets the length or angle of the first line. And other lines automatic update its point coordinate according to its length and angle which can **only be changed by the users**.

When SetLength of line0, line0's StartPoint stays still but its EndPoint changes.
EndPoint of Line 0 is StartPoint of Line 1. Next to Line1, Line1's angle and length doesn't get set by the user but its Startpoint connected to line0's EndPoint changed so Line1 will have different EndPoint. The same things go on with all others lines.

I want first line's change effect all other lines.

I've searched around and understood that properties (StartPoint,EndPoint) can't be reference in C#. Any workaround for properties StartPoint and StartPoint of class Line to be updated by the change from different Line instance.

Comment: Any workaround for what problem? You need to be clear and concise. Your post is concise but about as clear as mud.

Comment: Sorry, edited for more detail.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "property can't be reference in C#" for one thing. Your `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` declarations are invalid, too...

Comment: Your issue could have something to do with your line class declaration. You have "public Line" instead of "public class Line" maybe that is why it is saying it can't be referenced?

Comment: I understand English is not your mother tongue. And because of this, it is even more important that you write error messages verbatim in your question. Do not try to interpret error messages with your own words, as this will make understanding of your problem very difficult...

Comment: I described question more specifically. Tell me if you don't understand at some points.

Comment: Yeh... I'm out... your post still doesn't make much sense to me, sorry! @JonSkeet I can't believe you're real! Love your work, keep it up!

Comment: *"When SetLength of line0, line0's StartPoint stays still but its EndPoint changes."* - I highly doubt that since your `SetLength` method does absolutely nothing at all.

Comment: Can you re-check the code one more time? i've just given more details into it.

Comment: Your example is *just* calling constructors. You never even call `SetLength` in your sample code. It's still not clear what you're asking. Please provide a [mcve]. It also really doesn't help that your code is badly formatted - format it all in Visual Studio. I'd also strongly suggest giving your `Point` class two properties, `X` and `Y` rather than using an array for no obvious reason.

Comment: i have taken your advice and re-formated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both `SetLength()` and `SetAngle()`, you're creating a **NEW** Point instance to update your Line.  This means that particular Line instance will reference the newly created Point, but all the other Line instances will still reference the originally created Point.

Simply change:

```
EndPoint = new Point(x2, y2);
```

To:

```
EndPoint.X = x2;
EndPoint.Y = y2;
```

Make sure to do this in both of your functions!

Comment: I tried it that way but it only changes the second line. The third line won't get changed. I want first line's change effect all other lines.

Comment: You will need to write the code to propagate this kind of change through all the lines/points then, this can't be handled by a simple reference.

Comment: I get stucked at that for a while now. Can you give me some clues?

Comment: I see I misunderstood your requirements.  Your current approach can't handle propagation because you have three separately declared instances of Line.  You could hard-code a change that affects all Lines, but what happens when you move to four points?...five points?  Your Lines don't actually "point" to each other, what they have are "points in common".  What you need is either a (1) `List<Line>` so that you can iterate over all the Lines and update them accordingly, or (2) Change Class Line so that it literally **references** the next (or multiple) Lines like a Linked List or Tree Structure.

Comment: Approach (2) makes more sense as with approach (1) you'll have to track which new Point(s) have been touched and then keep iterating over the List<Line> over and over making changes to any new Lines touched until everything is updated.  You'll have to account for **Closed Loops** with either approach as you could end up in infinite cycles.  More context might be helpful, here.  How are you using these classes?

Comment: What is your desired context ? I think I put a lot of usage contexts in the top-most post.

Comment: I want the top inputed line as base line. line0's StartPoint is the base in the example and won't get changed except for directly assign into it. When you SetLength line2, it won't effect line0 and line1 but line3, line4... (which connects in to line2).

Comment: I really think you need to be thinking in terms of [Nodes and Graphs](http://www.vcskicks.com/representing-graphs.php).

Comment: I will reseach on what you suggested.

Comment: Sorry to make this excuse, can you give me a code example to make use of graphs in my problem? I still can't make use of those given theory.

Comment: What you're asking for is usually taught at the **END** of a "Data Structures and Algorithms" class.  You need a firm grasp of Object Oriented Programming and usually tackle linked lists, stacks, queues, binary trees, AVL trees, etc...before getting to generic graphs.

Comment: You might be able to use one of the easier structures I listed, but the requirements and possibilities of your "lines" problem haven't been explained in great enough detail to know if this is the case or not.